# Application_BeginRequest do not show request for .js and .css files

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net

I wanted to add headers to response based on file types. What i am trying to do is add cache-control headers to response if the file type is .js or .css. For some reason, I don't see request for files with .js, .css file types in my Application_BeginRequest. I have put a break point in Application_BeginRequest and tried to view Request.Url.LocalPath and none of the requests are for .js or .css files. I am sure that the page has link to .js and .css. I see requests for .js and .css file in Chrome Dev Tool, just that I cannot see requests for those files in Application_BeginRequest.

I have also tried to hard refresh my page (Ctrl+F5) to make sure that the browser is not requesting those files from Cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely because you don't have the .net pipeline configured in such as way for these static files to enter the pipeline.  More than likely these static files are being served directly by your webserver (probably IIS) and the request for them does not enter your asp.net request pipeline.

Assuming that you are using integrated pipeline mode, you can get them to enter the pipeline with the following addition to your web.config.  In the `<system.webServer><handlers>` section you can add this:

```
  <add name="js-files--use-integrated-pipeline" path="*.js" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
  <add name="css-files--use-integrated-pipeline" path="*.css" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
```

With this addition you will see the requests come into the `Application_BeginRequest`.

There are other ways also to add custom headers.  You could look into the settings that can be set in the web.config in the `<system.webServer><httpProtocol><customHeaders>` section.